# Stop scientific notation in uitable

Tags: matlab, uitableview, matlab-guide, scientific-notation, matlab-uitable

I use GUIDE to create a `uitable` and load data into it, which looks like:

[image: uitable image]

My question is: How to display the numbers without using scientific notation?

I have tried this but failed:

```
format long g  
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',data)
```

Furthermore, since I will do some calculation of the number and save it to an excel file, I wish it could remain as a numeric array, not changing it to string.

Comment: Pleae read the tag excerpts for tags you want to use. I changed [guide] to [matlab-guide]. And don't forget to add the language next time.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the table in your .fig file, right click on the table and select "Table Property Editor".
- At the column definitions, you will see a column named "Format".
  Choose custom from the dropdown as shown below:

  [image: Table Property Editor]
- Now choose how you want the output to be.

  [image: Custom Format Editor]